# How to download Wordpress 4.2.0

Tags: installation

I am trying to download Wordpress 4.2.0, not 4.2.3.

I go to the downloads page here 
https://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/

Every time I download 4.2 and install it, the admin tells me that 4.2.3 is installed.

Why does the link that says "4.2" download 4.2.3? Am I missing something?

Comment: Presumably you're using it with a clean new database each time?

Comment: Yes I was. Denis's advice got it fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's auto-update (since 4.2.3 is a security one). Try disabling the auto updates prior to WP installation via wp-config.php. [Here is an](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates) article on that. Follow the "[Famous 5-Minute Install](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress#Famous_5-Minute_Install)" but rename manually the wp-config.php file and disable the auto updates first before proceeding installing the WP.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work.

Comment: Hmm. Let me try install it. Will get back in a few minutes.

Comment: Yes my bad. I've forgot about **WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE**. Here are the lines you need to add:

`define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );`

`define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );`

Comment: Awesome it works. Sorry about the late reply.